# UITableView won´t let me scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I cannot get this tableView with a `UIView` on top to work properly. What happens is that the cells got a check mark in it´s accessory view and in `viewDidLoad` I want to make all cells show that checkmark. So I "tap" the `Select all` button in code.

```
[self.selectToggleButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but when I do this, it won´t let me scroll the `tableView`, or it does - but it wont let me
scroll to the bottom as it constantly jumps back to the initial position, until i tap the `Select all` button, and then it works fine.

[image]

## pragma mark - IBActions

```
- (IBAction)selectAllRows:(id)sender {
    
    [self.selectedSongs removeAllObjects];
    [self.selectedCells removeAllObjects];
    NSUInteger numberOfSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (NSUInteger s = 0; s < numberOfSections; ++s) {
        NSUInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:s];
        for (NSUInteger r = 0; r < numberOfRowsInSection; ++r) {
            NSIndexPath *idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s];
            [self.selectedCells addObject:idxPath];
            [self.selectedSongs addObject:self.allSongs[idxPath.row]];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (IBAction)deselectAll:(id)sender {
    [self.selectedSongs removeAllObjects];
    [self.selectedCells removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)toggleAll:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([self.allSongs count] == [self.selectedSongs count]) {
                [sender setTitle:@"Select all" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self deselectAll:sender];
    } else {
        [sender setTitle:@"Deselect all" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self selectAllRows:sender];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.allSongs.count;
}
```

Comment: What is the handler code for TouchUpInside event? Are you calling `sendActionsForControlEvents:` from the main thread?

Comment: @Alex: updated the Q, everything is happening in the main thread. But I do not "ask for the main thread" via GCD or something. Everything is just written plainly. (Toggle all is called when button is pressed)

Comment: Can you post your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method?

Comment: @Yazid: I have updated - however I doubt that is the problem - I know how that mehtod works

Comment: Thanks, didn't mean to imply that you didn't. Simply trying to understand how you've implemented your `UITableViewDataSource` protocol since I saw that your `selectAllRows` method seems to be interacting with 2 possible data source arrays. Can you help explain a little bit about how you've implemented `self.selectedSongs` and `self.selectedSongs`?

Comment: "I want to make all cells show that checkmark" - It is the job of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to make that kind of thing happen. You maintain state somewhere, so that each time `reloadData` is called, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` knows whether to put the checkmark accessory view or no accessory view.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned wanting to have all cells show a checkmark during `viewDidLoad`, did you consider doing `[cell setSelected:YES]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Can you show which other delegate / data source methods you have.